# Assign Search Single String Multiple Data to Move File With A Certain Name

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I needed a batch file which could move multiple .txt files based on their names. This is a daily task so I wanted to optimize it. Basically, when the batch is run, it will first create a folder with the current date in assigned folders. This part is working smoothly. The second part is setting the search strings. Originally, I had hard-coded individual search strings like this:

```
set searchString1=1
set searchString2=2
set searchString3=3
set searchString4=4
set searchString5=5
```

This is working fine, but as the strings increase, I want to optimize it.

This is the entire code:

```
@echo off
set currentDate=%date:~-4,4%"-"%date:~-7,2%"-"%date:~0,2%
set baseFolderPath=C:\Users\1\My Drive

set "folderPath1=%baseFolderPath%\ABC"
set "folderPath2=%baseFolderPath%\DEF"
set "folderPath3=%baseFolderPath%\GHI"
set "folderPath4=%baseFolderPath%\JKL"
set "folderPath5=%baseFolderPath%\MNO"

mkdir "%folderPath1%\%currentDate%"
mkdir "%folderPath2%\%currentDate%"
mkdir "%folderPath3%\%currentDate%"
mkdir "%folderPath4%\%currentDate%"
mkdir "%folderPath5%\%currentDate%"

set searchStringData1=1, 2, 3, 4
set searchStringData2=5
set searchStringData3=6, 7 
set searchStringData4=8
set searchStringData5=9, 0

move C:\Users\1\Downloads\*"%searchStringData1%"**.txt* "%folderPath1%\%currentDate%"
move C:\Users\1\Downloads\*"%searchStringData2%"**.txt* "%folderPath2%\%currentDate%"
move C:\Users\1\Downloads\*"%searchStringData3%"**.txt* "%folderPath3%\%currentDate%"
move C:\Users\1\Downloads\*"%searchStringData4%"**.txt* "%folderPath4%\%currentDate%"
move C:\Users\1\Downloads\*"%searchStringData5%"**.txt* "%folderPath5%\%currentDate%"

pause
```

When I run this batch, files with single data in the search string move. For example 5 and 8 move in the assigned folders, but others don't.

I'll be really grateful if someone could help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `FOR` operator like this:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a IN ("%searchStringData1%") DO (
   move C:\Users\1\Downloads\*"%a"**.txt* "%folderPath1%\%currentDate%"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in (eg) `C:\Users\1\Downloads\*"%searchStringData1%"**.txt*` the string assigned to `searchStringData1` is substituted, so your instruction is executed as `move C:\Users\1\Downloads\*"1, 2, 3, 4"**.txt*`. Since strings `2` and `4` contain just the digits `5` & `8` respectively, that works.

use

```
for %%e in (%searchStringData1%) do move C:\Users\1\Downloads\*%%e**.txt* …
```

which can be duplicated for each of your 5 cases, regardless of the number of characters in your `searchStringData?`

You could also use character strings in place of the single digits if you want - they just need to be separated by commas or spaces.